# Table Encryption in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt an entire table, not just a specific column in MySQL? I'm also using Drupapl & PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just using "AES_ENCRYPT"  for ENCRYPTwhen you insert a record.

```
 INSERT INTO table (mycolumn) VALUES(AES_ENCRYPT('Hello!', 'encryption_key'));
```

And using "AES_DECRYPT"  for DECRYPT  when you insert a record.

```
   SELECT AES_DECRYPT(mycolumn, 'encryption_key') FROM table;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I know this, but Im searching for any easy way to encrypt a whole table. Is not  there any easier or cleverer solution for this than encrypt it field by field? Or coulmn by column?

Comment: Hi only one method is there. And another way put this process code in trigger.